# How to get a queue from a consumer in JMS?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I have a code that gets a queue from browse, but I can't find a method that gets a queue from a consumer.Is it possible to get a queue from the consumer?

Method for getting a queue from browse:

```java
private void viewMessage() throws NamingException, JMSException {
    Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("dynamicQueues/" + "TestQueue");
    queueBrowser = queueSession.createBrowser(queue);
    System.out.println(queueBrowser.getQueue());
}
```

But I can't find a similar method, but in consumer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JMS [`MessageConsumer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/MessageConsumer.html) doesn't have a `getQueue()` method or any equivalent. However, every JMS [`Message`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html) you receive will have a [`getJMSDestination()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#getJMSDestination--) method which will return a [`Destination`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Destination.html) which represents where the message came from. Using this information you can deduce the destination to which the consumer is connected.